# Blackberry - create separate LocationProviders

Tags: blackberry, java-me, gps

I wish to create two separate LocationProvider instances, each using a different gps mode (assist, cellsite, etc.). The docs on LocationProvider.getInstance say that:

> *This method may, depending on the implementation, return the same
>   LocationProvider instance as has been returned previously from this
>   method to the calling application, if the same instance can be used to
>   fulfill both defined criteria*

Which seems a little vague - if I set different modes in the different criteria can I be sure I will get two different LocationProviders? If not, will creating them on two different threads do the trick?

Comment: +1! Yes, BB has very vague docs on this. I vaguely recall (because it was a year ago) I tried to implement smth similar, but without success - location updates came only to the last got `LocationProvider` instance. Please keep me updated on your results. Who knows - maybe your implementation will be beter than mine and you'll be able to monitor several LPs simultaneously.

Comment: Currently my tests show that I get a different object ID for the different modes, but the locations I latter get are from one provider! If there was at least a way to know for sure how it should behave!!

Comment: It sounds like you got the same situation as me.